# regular expression to extract @name symbols from tweet

Tags: c#, php, python, regex, perl

I would like to use regular expression to extract only `@patrick  @michelle` from the following sentence:

```
@patrick  @michelle we having diner @home tonight do you want to join?
```

Note: `@home` should not be include in the result because, it is not at beginning of the sentence nor is followed by another `@name`.

Any solution, tip, comments will be really appreciated.

Comment: If `@home` *were* followed by another `@name`, would *both* values be considered names, or just the first one? Are you aware that your rules don't match how people actually use Twitter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/(?:(?:@\S+\s+)+|^)@\S+/g
```

It first matches either an "@" followed by many non-space characters, or the start of line, and then matches another "@" followed by many non-space characters.

Note that it's common in Twitter that `@name` is preceded by `RT`, appears in the middle or end of the tweet e.g. http://twitter.com/ceetee/statuses/9874073403. Basically you can't distinguish whether a @name is really a name just using RegEx or even a parser. The best bet is to check if `http://twitter.com/name` 404 or not.

Comment: This seems to works well but only for 2. How can extend it to match n @name at the beginning of sentence.

Input: @patrick  @michelle @john @Ted we having diner @home tonight do you want to join?

Comment: Thanks Kenny, this is exactly what I want
Implementation in python
import re
msg = 'comes here'
re.findall('(?:(?:@\S+\s+)+|^)@\S+', msg)

Comment: Trouble is, testing "@home" *doesn't* return 404, and yet it's also not a Twitter account name.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at first I thought this failed because I looked at the groups that are returned:

```
>>> tw = re.compile(r"^((@\w*)\s+)*")
>>> tw.findall(tweet)
[('@michelle ', '@michelle')]
>>> tw.match(tweet).groups()
('@michelle ', '@michelle')
```

Note that the groups only keep the last value for any group in the re.  But if you just grab group(), then you get the whole matched string:

```
>>> tw.match(tweet).group()
'@patrick  @michelle '
```

For grins, I'll try pyparsing:

```
>>> from pyparsing import Word, printables, OneOrMore
>>> atName = Word("@",printables)
>>> OneOrMore(atName).parseString(tweet).asList()
['@patrick', '@michelle']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^\s*@(\w+)\s+@(\w+)/
```

`\s` denotes whitespace characters and `\w` word characters.

Comment: @Gumbo: I think Joey may be after something a bit more robust... your regexp wouldn't match if there was only a single name

Answer (score 0):

As long as it starts with an @ and continues with those this will do it I tested it in poweshell so some regex engines are a bit different.  This should also catch n names at the beginning of the line

"^((@\w+)\s)+"

Comment: You'd need to add a trailing space to the string before using that RE, though, to handle the case where the string ends with `@foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this, though you'll have to split on whitespace anything in the matching group to extract multiple ids.

```
/^\s*(@\w+\s+)*\s+.*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged your post c#, so I assume you can use the .NET Regex imnplementation.
Using .NET, the following Regex will do:

```
(?<![^@]\w+\s+)(@\w+)
```

This will match any words starting with @, that do not have a word without @ before them.
Note that "dinner @home @8pm" will still break it, though.

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

for PHP

```
/^\s*@(\w+)\s+@(\w+)/
```

Thanks KennyM

in python

```
msg = '@patrick  @michelle we having diner @home tonight do you want to join?'
import re
re.findall('(?:(?:@\S+\s+)+|^)@\S+', msg)
```

This works with 1 or n @name at the beginning of the sentence.

Thank you all for the quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, you can exploit the `/g` match-more-than-once modifier combined with the `\G` zero-width where-we-left-off assertion and list context, thus:

```
my $str = '@patrick  @michelle we having diner @home tonight do you want to join?';
my @matches = ($str =~ m/\G(\@\w+)\s*/g);

print join(', ', @matches) . "\n";
```

This should be robust across any number of initial @-strings.

Answer (score 0):

For Python check out: http://github.com/BonsaiDen/AtarashiiFormat
It will also give you the links and the tags.

And beware of using a simple regex, you will end up with a big mess, as I did before I converted the Twitter Text Java Library.

Answer (score 0):

For C# I would do as follows:

@([A-Za-z0-9-_&;]+)